# How do I declare so that the default tab will be highlighted in jquery mobile UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery. I'm creating an app UI with jquery mobile.

I got this sample from their web on mobile tabstrips. How do I declare so that the default tab will be under 'loans Due' and its tab will be highlighted.

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li id="loansDue"><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">Loans Due</a></li>
                <li id="overDue"><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Overdue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/109</a></li>
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/110</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/106</a></li>
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/107</a></li>
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/108</a></li>
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/109</a></li>
                <li><a href="loanInfo.html">AY1415S2/110</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 1 });
```

and

```
var SelectedTab = $('ul li#loansDue').index();

$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: SelectedTab  })
```

but none of them works. Please advise.

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: jquery 1.11.1 and jquery mobile 1.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use active property - where "1" denotes the index of the tab

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6jud1q7/1/)

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  active: 1
});
```

Comment: tried but it stil doesn't work. It is cuz I did not declare index but id for my tabs?

Comment: its working - it loads Loans Due - but does not apply the css --http://jsfiddle.net/p6jud1q7/

Comment: @EtAndrea - focus of tab also taken care off .. please check the latest jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do as below just add this script.

```
$(function(){
    $("#loansDue").addClass("ui-state-hover");
    $("#loansDue a").addClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```

This is not a proper way but I have tested it and its just working fine.
Feel free to ask anything.
Thanks.

Comment: The first tab is already selected but the problem is that `li` and `a` tags are missing those two css classes.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should select the tab with index 1

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Created a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/xdgcycud/